# Trignometric Indentities

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove the following identity: $4\sin^2x + 7\cos^2x = 4 + 3\cos^2x$

I have no idea where to start on these type of trigonometric identities with the numbers in front of the sin and cos.

Comment: There is a fundamental trigonometric identity which involves $\cos^2x$ and $\sin^2x$. Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
4\sin^2x+7\cos^2x=4\sin^2x+4\cos^2x+3\cos^2x=4+3\cos^2x
$$

Comment: Wow thank you. Now I understand how to finish the rest of my homework!